# How to read text file from filesystem in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried different approaches to read a text file from the local file system in JavaScript and display the content of the file in `alert()` but all to no avail.

Approach 1

```
function readTextFile(file) {
          var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
           rawFile.open("GET", file , false);

          rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
              if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
                  if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                      var allText = rawFile.response;
                     document.getElementById("content").innerText = allText;
                      alert(allText);
                  }
              } else {
                  alert("Can't read the file");
              }
          }
          rawFile.send(null);
    }
    readTextFile("FormulaQuestion.txt");
```

The **FormulaQuestion.txt** file is in the same directory with the html file, this approach shows an empty alert window on the browser

**Approach 2 using fetch method**

```
fetch('FormulaQuestion.txt')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then((data) => {
            alert(data);
        })
```

This doesn't show anything

**Approach 3 using JQuery**

```
$.get('FormulaQuestion.txt', function (data) {
        alert(data)
    }, 'text');
```

This doesn't work either.

I am building a desktop application that uses a web browser control to load html file which is embedded into the application. The application reads the string from sqlite database and save it in the **FormulaQuestion.txt** file, then refreshes the WebControl component which reloads the html file.
Now when the html file is reloaded, the JavaScript should read the text file and display it on **alert()** which once the alert is able to display the file content, i will then set it to a paragraph and remove the **alert()**.
Please someone should help me out.

Comment: Just think about all the wonderful hacking that would become possible if arbitrarily reading files off the user's disk were permitted.. That'll help inform you as to why it doesn't

Comment: You cannot access your local hard disk with javascript.

Comment: You can't do that and I'd be frightened if you could. Any website could freely scan anybody's hard disk in the background. Browsers will never allow Javascript to do this. Node.js, on the other hand, not being a browser, does.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers by design do not allow access to the file system for JavaScript, as allowing such access would be a serious security concern.

To provide the FormulaQuestion.txt file to your script you will need to host the file on a server and request it via a HTTP request (like with your fetch). The key thing here is that a server is needed to actually transmit the file over the HTTP protocol to your script.

If working locally, there are many options for running a local server.

- The npm serve module,
- Wamp
- Apache

You may also want to try out some free tier services like Vercel or Netlify. Both I believe allow you to just drag/drop a file and it will host it for you.

Comment: Shade of difference, browsers do perfectly have access to the file system (proof is, they can download files and save them to the disk, and also you can drop an image from the file system to the browser). They are OS-level applications. But they don't _allow_ Javascript to access it (Javascript is sandboxed in the browser)

Comment: Quite right. Updated accordingly.

Comment: Please which approach can I use to read string from a local db and send it to my html file?

Comment: It depends on the technology stack you're using, e.g., the exact database, and what server you'll be using to serve the files. For example, you might have a MySQL database which you could query with PHP to return the string, which could be served by apache server, for instance.

Comment: The application uses an embedded SQLite database. once the user installs the app, the db file is also copied to the client machine and now i need a way to retrieve value from the database and use it in the html file. This doesn't involve any server technology.

Comment: It again depends on how all this is being executed. I'm going to have a guess here - it sounds like you're running some kind of install process which completes and then you want to present the user with an HTML file. I'm guessing you're presenting the HTML file locally by launching a browser with a path to the local HTML file. This is a very different use case than browsing the internet, for example. If my guess is correct, then you must be running some code already, either an application or a script in the host OS. In either case you should be able to embed the data directly in the HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome, you need to run Chrome with the "--disable-web-security" command line parameter, but I don't know about Firefox/other browsers.

Comment: Obvious caveat: doing this can cause serious security problems; only use it for prototyping, and take care to not access any other web pages while the browser is on this mode.